# The fundamental theorem of calculus: Limit of the supremum of a function on a closed interval as the interval size approaches zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was reading the proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus in Spivak;

Assume we have a function $f(x)$ that is integrable on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and continuous at $c \in [a,b]$, suppose we have $h>0$, then he constructed the function:

$M(h) = sup\{f(x): c \leq x \leq c+h\}$

and then in the proof he said: $\lim_{h \to 0} M(h)=f(c)$ by the continuity of $f$ at $c$

Intuitively this is clear, but I couldn't write a proof for this limit on supremum thing.

Any clues on the proof of this limit?

**Edit**

From the continuity of at c, $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$, so we need to show that the limit of $\lim_{h \to 0} M(h) = \lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ (or $\lim_{h \to 0} f(c+h)$) , I couldn't establish this part

Comment: It follows from definition of continuity at $c$. Please show your effort.

Comment: from the continuity of at c, $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$, so we need to show that the limit of $\lim_{h \to 0} M(h) = \lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ (or $\lim_{h \to 0} f(c+h)$) , I couldn't establish this part

Comment: @geetha290krm any hints?

Answer (score 0):

First of all $M(h)\geq f(c)$ for any $h$, so $\lim_{h\to0}M(h)\geq f(c)$.

Then you show $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists H>0$ such that $h<H$ implies $M(h)\leq f(c)+\varepsilon$, which is trivial by continuity. Once you have that, letting $h\to0$ and $\varepsilon\to0$ will yield the result.